# How can I select rows with MAX(Column) when another column has distinct values in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

I have four columns like this.

```
Material  Description  Quantity         Date
    a         133       200     26-09-2016 12:33
    a         133       400     27-09-2016 10:33
```

I need to take the quantity from that material when Max(Date);

I tried this but if quantity is distinct in shows both rows.

```
Select material , description , quantity , max(date)
FROM  materials
group by material, description , quantity
```

Comment: use max date in you where clause then..

Comment: What version of Oracle? (Always state that, and if you don't know, find out by running `select * from v$version`.) In Oracle 12, you can use `fetch first|last` and avoid a subquery.

Answer (score 2):

Use that condition in `WHERE` clause like

```
Select material , description , quantity 
FROM  materials
WHERE "Date"  = (select max("Date") from materials)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`RANK()` analytic function](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions123.htm):

```
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT materials,
         description,
         quantity,
         date,
         RANK() OVER ( PARTITION BY materials ORDER BY date DESC ) AS rnk 
  FROM   materials
)
WHERE  rnk = 1;
```

This will get multiple rows if there are rows with the same `materials` and maximum `date` values - if you only want a single row then use `ROW_NUMBER()` instead of `RANK()`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [row_number()](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions137.htm) like this (i'am add material b, if you need find quantity for all materials in group "a" and "b"):

```
WITH a(Material, Description , Quantity , sDate) AS
  (SELECT 'b',    133,    1200 ,    to_date('26-09-2016 12:33','dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi')  FROM dual  UNION ALL
   SELECT 'b',    133,    2200 ,    to_date('29-09-2016 12:33','dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi')  FROM dual  UNION ALL
   SELECT 'a',    133,    200 ,    to_date('26-09-2016 12:33','dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi')  FROM dual  UNION ALL
   SELECT 'a',    133,    400 ,    to_date('27-09-2016 10:33','dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi')  FROM dual  )
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT a.*,
               row_number() over(partition BY material order by sdate DESC) rn
          FROM a)
 WHERE rn = 1


MATERIAL DESCRIPTION   QUANTITY SDATE             RN
-------- ----------- ---------- --------- ----------
a                133        400 27-SEP-16          1 
b                133       2200 29-SEP-16          1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT materials,
         description,
         quantity,
         date,
         RANK() OVER ( PARTITION BY materials ORDER BY date DESC ) AS rnk 
  FROM   materials
)
WHERE  rnk = 1;
```